# How to add previous and next button?

Tags: jquery

So my problem is that when user click on next button, it does not move on pagination.

This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/821/ so any suggestion how can I fix this? When I click next or prev it moves content but I can't get highlight numbers.

```
var pageSize = 3;
var currentpage = 1;
var pagecount = 0;
var page_count = document.getElementById('page_count').value;

showPage = function (page) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content").each(function (n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();
    });
}

showPage(1);

$("#pagin li a.numbers").click(function () {
    $("#pagin li a.numbers").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text()));
});

$("#pagin").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    if ($(this).html() == "next") {
        $("#pagin li a.numbers").removeClass("current");

        currentpage++;
        console.log(currentpage);
    }
    else if ($(this).html() == "prev") {
        currentpage--;
    }
    else {
        currentpage = $(this).html();
    }
    if (currentpage < 1) {
        currentpage = 1;
    }
    if (currentpage > page_count) {
        currentpage = page_count;
    }
    showPage(currentpage);
});
```

Comment: `$("#pagin li a.numbers").click(function() {` You're assigning your click handler to an `a` with the class `numbers`. But the buttons don't have this class

Comment: if i put same class for buttons it will not work

Comment: Then add another class for your prev and next buttons. http://jsfiddle.net/jfm9y/822/

Comment: @Demnogonis problem is when i hit next it changes content but class is not added on numbers ...for example im on last page but first one is highlighted

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misread the question. +1 for StoYan :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add IDs to every button. Like this for example:

```
<li><a id="btn1" class="current" href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a id="btn2" href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a id="btn3" href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a id="btn4" href="#">4</a></li>
```

and add this in your JS after `showPage(currentpage);`

```
$(".current").removeClass("current");
$("#btn"+currentpage).addClass("current");
```

Comment: i need previous and next buttons also

Comment: my bad i didnt see that is working for previous and next also